# Why do we use SharePoint.client.dll and SharePoint.client.Runtime.dll

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Please explain the use of SharePoint.client.dll and SharePoint.client.Runtime.dll in C# coding.

Answer (score 0):

These dlls are used for using Client object model in Sharepoint. That is using this you can connect to sharepoint and perform operations on Sharepoint site.

With the client-side object model, developers have the ability to perform core SharePoint functionality by using C# (managed client object model).Client Side Object Model (CSOM) enables you to program against SharePoint lists and document libraries from client-side applications

http://aspe-it.com/blog/2014/client-side-object-model-in-sharepoint-2013/

Answer (score 0):

Client object model is newly introduced in SharePoint 2010 and it is a subset of Server Object model. As SharePoint’s object model is served based, many times developers want to write applications that need to talk to SharePoint from a client operating system and from client applications. Client object model brings a major portion of that rich server-side functionality as a Client-side API, which can be used in a .NET client such as a WPF application, in a Silverlight application, or in a simple client such as ECMAScript.

Read this for more indepth explanation: [What is Client Object Model in SharePoint 2010 ?](http://whatissharepointportal.blogspot.com/2012/12/what-is-client-object-model-in.html) and http://praveenbattula.blogspot.com/2010/02/sharepoint-2010-complete-details-about.html

Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 installs **Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll** and **Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll** in `%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\ISAPI` for easy access in development. You must have both **Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll** and **Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll** to develop a solution remotely with the .NET managed object model.

Answer (score 0):

Both dlls are deployed to folders beneath the SharePoint root when you install SharePoint 2010. So when you coding you will need to add them in C# code manually . Similarly you do the same with Silverlight apps using C# .